# jQuery edit and clone slider

Tags: jquery, slider, clone

I'm writing a jQuery slider's clone function, after add new time from slider, I want to change the time with edit button, but when I click edit, the slider can't slide, and the time isn't right, the slider shows the original slider's time, not the time that I added, how to fix it?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0z25gqk9/)

```js
$('#slider').slider({
 range: true,
 min: 0,
 max: 1440,
 step: 60,
 values: [400, 920],
   
 slide: function (e, ui) {
  var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
  var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

  if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
  if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
  if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
  if (hours1 < 10) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
  if (hours1 == 24) {
   hours1 = "23";
   minutes1 = "59";
  }

  $('.time1').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);

  var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
  var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

  if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
  if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
  if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
  if (hours2 < 10) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
  if (hours2 == 24) {
   hours2 = "23";
   minutes2 = "59";
  }

  $('.time2').html(hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
 }
});

$('#add').click(function() {
    var Time = $('.time1').html() + ' - ' + $('.time2').html();
 
    var row = '<tr class="myRows">'
      + '<td class="rowTime">' + Time + '</td>'
   + '<td><div><button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></div></td>'
   + '</tr>';

 $(row).insertAfter($("#form > tbody > tr:last"));
 $("#slider").slider('values', [400, 920]);
    $('.time1').text('07:00');
 $('.time2').text('15:00');
});

$('#form').on('click','.edit',function() {
 var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowTime = $row.find('.rowTime');
 var times = rowTime.text();
 rowTime.html($('#sliderTime').clone());
 rowTime.each(function() {
  $(this).html();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sliderTime">
    <span class="time1">07:00</span> - <span class="time2">15:00</span>
 <br><br>
 <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<table id="form">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
   <th>Table Rules</th>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code it will work fine as you stated what you want :). what i'm doing is `wrapping the sliders inside an function` and `calling` it first on `page load` and after when you `click on edit the function is being called again` and the sliders do `initialize` again :) . function called : `loadsliders();`

```
loadslides();
function loadslides(){
var sliders = $('.slider');
sliders.each(function(){
    $(this).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 60,
    values: [400, 920],

    slide: function (e, ui) {
        var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
        var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

        if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
        if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
        if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
        if (hours1 < 10) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
        if (hours1 == 24) {
            hours1 = "23";
            minutes1 = "59";
        }

        $(this).siblings('.time1').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);

        var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
        var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

        if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
        if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
        if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
        if (hours2 < 10) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
        if (hours2 == 24) {
            hours2 = "23";
            minutes2 = "59";
        }

        $(this).siblings('.time2').html(hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
    }
});
});
}
$('#add').click(function() {
    var Time = $('.time1').html() + ' - ' + $('.time2').html();

    var row = '<tr class="myRows">'
            + '<td class="rowTime">' + Time + '</td>'
            + '<td><div><button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></div></td>'
            + '</tr>';

    $(row).insertAfter($("#form > tbody > tr:last"));
    $(".slider").slider('values', [400, 920]);
    $('.time1').text('07:00');
    $('.time2').text('15:00');
});

$('#form').on('click','.edit',function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowTime = $row.find('.rowTime');
    var times = rowTime.text();
    rowTime.html($('.sliderTime').clone());
    loadslides();
    rowTime.each(function() {
        $(this).html();
    });
});
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0z25gqk9/1/

jsfiddle working without any time reset :

http://jsfiddle.net/0z25gqk9/2/

Comment: Thx a lot！I have one more question, if I add 11:00 - 12:00 at first time, then when I click edit button, the time reset to the default value in the table rules (07:00 - 15:00), how to make it stay in 11:00 - 12:00, not the default time? Thx!

Comment: @S.P.  thats because you are completely removing the content of cloned row and adding the copy of .slideTime's content again , which does reset the values

Comment: @S.P.  i have added a fiddle in my answer the second fiddle , it will help you way more :) .

Comment: @S.P.  the second fiddle is working and not resetting any time :) , use it's html structure as well as jquery.

Comment: @S.P. if it solved your problem then you should accept the answer :)

Comment: I'm on the bus, will try it later and accept it, thank you!

Comment: Hello, I tried, it works perfectly. I'm wondering the slider part, how to make **values: [400, 920]** match the **('.time1').html** and **('.time2').html**? It won't reset again, but the slider reset, do you know how to fix? Thank you!!